# C# inheritance primitive type must be 'object' to match overridden member

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an abstract class with an abstract method that returns an object type:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    public abstract object MyAbstractMethod();
}
```

And I have implemented this class correctly with non primitive types, like this:

```
public class MyClass : MyAbstractClass
{   
    public override string MyAbstractMethod()
    {
        return "Hi StackOverflow !!!";
    }
}
```

But when I try to use primitive types, like bool, int... etc like this:

```
public class MyClass : MyAbstractClass
{   
    public override bool MyAbstractMethod()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> type must be 'object' to match overridden member

**I know why it's happening**, it's because a primitive type is not an object but...

How can I fix this without wrapping primitive type inside an object? Is possible?

Comment: You could make it generic, as `public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> { public abstract T MyAbstractMethod(); }`

Comment: ^^ Also consider using a generic interface instead.

Comment: **Type covariance** only works on reference-types: including `System.Object`, `String`, et-cetera, while _value-types_ like `bool` (`System.Boolean`), `Int32`, etc exist in a completely separate type-hierarchy (they don't really "inherit" from `System.Object` despite the docs, that's a quirk of .NET's metadata system and how .NET uses `Object` as [a poor-man's Top-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type).

Comment: _"it's because a primitive type is not an object but..."_ - The term "primitive type" has no relevance here - what matters are _reference-types_ vs. _value-types_. Arguably C#/.NET has _primitive-types_ that are also reference-types (like `Object` and `String`, depending on who you ask).

Comment: ^^ Maybe you've heard "reference type with value-type semantics" before ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) comment (and thanks to the rest of the people for explaining to me exactly why c# does not allow this behavior) I managed to solve it using the following code:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T>
{
    public abstract T MyAbstractMethod();
}

public class MyClassString : MyAbstractClass<string>
{
    public override string MyAbstractMethod()
    {
        return "Hi StackOverflow !!!";
    }
}

public class MyClassBool : MyAbstractClass<bool>
{
    public override bool MyAbstractMethod()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    public abstract object MyAbstractMethod();
}

public class MyClassString : MyAbstractClass
{
    public override string MyAbstractMethod()
    {
        return "Hi StackOverflow !!!";
    }
}

public class MyClassBool : MyAbstractClass
{
    public override bool MyAbstractMethod()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Imagine a method `M` which has a reference to `MyAbstractClass` and is calling the abstract `MyAbstractMethod`. `M` expects to get back `object`, a reference type. There is no way it can accept arbitrary value types (technically and as a matter of implementation details: for small value types that fit into a pointer there would be no way to pass the type of the return value or to distinguish between reference types and integers, and for large value types the calling convention is different as return values are passed out by reference essentially via a hidden `out` argument). So value types have to be boxed to 'fit' the same call site.

Comment: It didn't necessarily _have_ to be this way though - .NET could have been designed to allow _strongly-typed_ boxing of value-types without needing to lose static type information (as we do today by having to use `Object` as a top-type) - whereas Java went with that approach which is why you can return an `int` boxed via `java.lang.Integer` without using `Object`. Fortunately this isn't a huge problem in practice, but still less-than-ideal.

Comment: Isn't an `int` boxed via `java.lang.Integer` a heap-allocated object, though?